# Automorphisms over finite field that do not lift to an automorphism in characteristic zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, automorphism-groups, positive-characteristic

My main question is the following: is there an automorphism of the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ **(automorphism of an algebraic variety)** defined over a finite field which does not lift to an automorphism defined over a field in characteristic zero?

Let us first consider finite fields of the form $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$. If you take an automorphism $f$ of the affine space that is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and such that $p$ does not divide any of the denominators of $f$ and of $f^{-1}$, you may consider the restriction of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ to automorphisms defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, by considering the coefficients modulo $p$, and get automorphisms defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Is every automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ obtained by this way? (one can do similar constructions for other finite fields and other fields of caracteristic zero).

For each prime $p$, every linear automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^n$, given by $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto (a_{11}x_1+\cdots +a_{1n}x_n,\ldots,a_{n1}x_1+\cdots +a_{nn}x_n)$ for some matrix $(a_{ij})\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ comes from an element of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ whose entries are integers and whose determinant is not divisible by $p$. Its inverse in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ has thus all denominators that are not multiple of $p$. Hence, every linear automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ comes from a linear automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Similarly, if you take an elementary automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^n$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e. given by
$$(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (x_1+a(x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n),x_2,\ldots,x_n)$$
for some polynomial $a\in \mathbb{F}_p[x_2,\ldots,x_n]$, it comes from an automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^n$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ (here even over $\mathbb{Z}$). In particular, every "tame" automorphism  (generated by linear and elementary automorphisms)  of $\mathbb{A}^n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ comes from a tame automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. In dimension $n=1$ and $n=2$, every automorphism is tame, so every automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ comes from an automorphism defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. The question is then more interesting for $n\ge 3$. It would give examples of non-tame automorphisms, a fact not know until now in positive characteristic (see the famous article [Shestakov and Umirbaev - The tame and the wild automorphisms of polynomial rings in three variables](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2004-17-01/S0894-0347-03-00440-5) for examples in characteristic zero).

This seems hard to answer in general, but can we then replace the variety $\mathbb{A}^n$ by an affine (or projective) algebraic variety, defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and find some automorphisms over $\mathbb{F}_p$ that do not come from automorphisms in characteristic zero?

EDIT: Will Sawin gave a nice answer for elliptic curves, where some given automorphism do not lift to $\mathbb{Q}$. Are there examples where some given automorphisms do not lift to any field of caracteristic zero?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "restriction of an automorphism defined over a field in charactersitic zero"? How would you restrict an automorphism over $\mathbb Q$ (say) to one over $\mathbb F_p$?

Comment: After you clarify what "come from an automorphism in characteristic zero" should mean, you should consider the Frobenius automorphism $x\mapsto x^p$ for fields of prime characteristic $p$. It's the identity on the prime field $\mathbb Z/p$ but nontrivial on all larger fields of characteristic $p$. I can't think of any reasonable sense in which this comes from an automorphism in characteristic zero.

Comment: The Frobenius is not an automorphism.

Comment: If you have an automorphism of an algebraic variety, defined over $\mathbb{Z}$, it gives you an automorphism over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for any prime $p$. The question is whether any automorphism defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is obtained from this way (you can do similar constructions for other finite fields). In the case of $\mathbb{A}^n$ I do not know any example which is not like this and would be interesting if some exists. I am also interested in other automorphisms of algebraic varieties (preferably affine).

Comment: @Jérémy: if you really mean "over $\mathbb{Z}$" then already the automorphism $x \mapsto 2x$ of $\mathbb{A}^1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ odd is not the restriction of an automorphism of $\mathbb{A}^1$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. (But it *is* a restriction (suitably interpreted) of an automorphism over a field of characteristic zero, namely $\mathbb{Q}$, which is what you originally wrote. So it would be good to clarify what you mean here.)

Comment: Whoops, $p \ge 5$. @Wojowu: restricting an automorphism over $\mathbb{Q}$ to one over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (for all but finitely many primes $p$) can be done by considering the denominators which occur in each polynomial defining the automorphism and avoiding them. In other words we lift (uniquely) from $\mathbb{Q}$ to a localization $S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ at finitely many primes, then consider quotients of that localization.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : thanks! Of course you are right, and I should have said $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$. I edited the question explaining what I meant by "restriction of an automorphism in caracteristic zero". I explained the case of $\mathbb{F}_p$, for prime $p$, which is already interested enough. For $\mathbb{F}_4$, one could consider $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ with denominators not multiple by $2$ and get an automorphism over $\mathbb{F}_4=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: @JeremyBlanc: "The Frobenius is not an automorphism." My post is about to become voted down, hence I write a comment here as well: To me it seems the Frobenius $f$ is an injective ring endomorphism of $K:=\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ (since $K$ is a field and the kernel of $f$ is an ideal $I=(0)$, which must be the zero ideal), and since $K$ is finite, it follows $f$ must be surjective: Any injective endomorphism of a finite set must be surjective.

Comment: PS: The comment I made below to the original formulation of the question of Jeremy Blanc was reasonable and for this reason I think it should remain on the site.

Comment: By an automorphism of a variety we usually mean an automorphism over the field. For affine varieties this is equivalent to a ring automorphism that preserves every element of the base field.

Comment: If $E$ is an elliptic curve then $E$ minus a point is an affine variety, whose automorphisms are the automorphisms of $E$. The elliptic curve $y^2 =x^3-x$ has an automorphisms of order $4$ over $\mathbb F_p$ when $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$, but not over $\mathbb Q$ - in fact, no elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ has an automorphism of order $4$.

Comment: @WillSawin Nice example of automorphism of an elliptic curve. A priori, it could be that you have an automorphism $f$ of the same curve, defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, such that the restriction modulo $p$ gives you the automorphism $\hat{f}$ of order $4$ that you mention. Why is it not possible? If $\hat{f}$ has order $4$, then $f$ does not necessarily have order $4$, no? It could be of infinite order for instance, no?

Comment: @JérémyBlanc All automorphisms of punctured elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$ have order $2$ (because they come from automorphisms of the projective curve that fix one point, hence have finite order, and also hence correspond to automorphisms of the group, and these act faithfully on the tangent space at the identity, which is $\mathbb Q$.)

Comment: @JeremyBlanc: It is better if you write the details of your comment in a post or in your mail above  - As you can see from my mails - the subject is delicate and you need to write down the maps you describe in full detail. It is difficult to dechiphre what maps you speak about. Write it down explicitly in your post.

Comment: @WillSawin nice. This looks like a good answer to me. Can you turn it into an answer?

Comment: When you let the Frobenius automorphism act on a polynomial ring over a field of characteristic $p>0$, it acts on the coefficients of the polynomial. If the base field is the finite field $k$ with $p$ elements, it acts as the identity endomorphism. If the base field has dimension $r$ over $k$ it is no longer the identity automorphism. I believe this was the reason for the comment of Blass above -

Comment: it seems this automorphism does not come from characteric zero, since taking p-powers is not a map of rings in characteristic zero. And this was your initial question - does there exist automorphisms in char $p$ that does not come from an automorphism in characteristic zero.

Comment: Well, it you take such a non-trivial automorphism of an affine variety, and compose it with the Frobenius on $k(r)$, the composed map will be an automorphism, and it seems to me it will not come from characteristic zero for the same reason.

Comment: For instance: If some of the non-tame automorphisms in the above mentioned JAMS paper exist for $k(r)$ in char $p>0$, you may compose one of these with the Frobenius and get a non-tame automorphism that does not come from characteristic zero.

Comment: The composition of two automorphisms of an affine algebraic variety $X$ is again an automorphism: The set of automorphisms $Aut(X)$ of $X$ is a group with composition as group multiplication.

Comment: I believe that if you try to study some of the results in the JAMS paper using the language presented in my posts below, it might be you can construct such examples. We must ask the administrators on this site to "upvote/undelete" these posts.

Comment: Of couse the set Aut(X) of automorphisms of $X$ is a group, but the Frobenius is *not* inside. The JAMS paper is already in the language of automorphisms of $k$-algebras. We can go in chat if you want.

Comment: PS: I have included an example (Example 1) in my previous post, and you should read this. You find all details if you ask the administrators to "undelete" the post.

Comment: @hm2020, you keep referring to "'undelet[ing]' the post", by which I assume you mean your answers.  Your answers ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/a/380774) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/a/380857)—I'm not sure why two rather than just one longer one) are not deleted.  As to [asking moderators to upvote your answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380763/automorphisms-over-finite-field-that-do-not-come-from-an-automorphism-in-charact#comment967643_380763), that is not a moderator's role (although of course they might choose to upvote it as individual users).

Comment: I have added some comments in Example 1. And it seems you must work over the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$. You can get similar examples working with arbitrary finite rank vector bundles over $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K$ is any number field.

Comment: It seems you must work with  $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ or $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_{\mathcal{O}_K}$ with $K$ a number field.

Comment: @LSpice: In my post I answer the question posed by Blanc - I believe there is a problem when annonymous users are downvoting a post that is answering a question. Should we "open up" the voting process and make it more transparent?

Comment: @JeremyBlanc: I have added an example of a finite rank vector bundle over the ring of integers in a number field, where a global automorphism acts on the fiber. I give an explicit example of a non-trivial  automorphism of the fiber that does not come from a global automorphism.

Comment: @JeremyBlanc: It seems now the post I wrote was deleted by Trimble and Petersen - I did not get an explanation for this deletion. My claim was as follows: Given an automorphism of a geometric vector bundle over $\mathcal{O}_K$, it will for any point in the base induce an automorphism of the fiber at that point. If the point has residue field with positive characteristic, the frobenius will act and this map will not lift to a global automorphism in general....

Comment: If you can lift an automorphism, a lifting will induce an action on the special fiber (the fiber over the generic point). Ask Trimble to "undelete" the post if you want details.

Comment: @JeremyBlanc: My answer was phrased in terms of automorphisms of affine schemes, hence it was indeed related to your questions. Ask Petersen or Trimble to "undelete" the post - I give all details in the post that was recently deleted.

Comment: @JeremyBlanc: Alternatively you can post a new separate question on the site where you specifically ask me to publish the "deleted" mail with all its details.

Comment: @hm2020 automorphisms of affine schemes or algebraic varieties, same thing. You simply should consider $Aut_K(A)$ for some $K$-algebra $A$. Hence automorphisms of $A$ that fix $K$. This is not what you did.

Comment: @JeremyBlanc - post another question on the site where you specifically ask me to publish the "deleted" answer and I will do it. Then you can read the answer and comment on details.  Science should not be about "downvoting" by annonymous users in my opinion.

Comment: @hm2020: You had the possibility to explain your point. We discussed. In the end, it did not work. I am not sure that you understood why, but that happens. If you want to discuss more about this, send me an e-mail or discuss on chat. I think that so many messages on this questions looks like spam now.

Comment: @hm2020 I voted to delete your two long answers since they did not answer the question. I suggest that you delete your comments here, and if you want to discuss this further you can post a thread on meta.mathoverflow.net .

Answer (score 8):

Some simple examples are provided by affine elliptic curves.

Recall that a smooth genus zero curves $E$ over a field $k$ with a rational point $P$ has a natural group structure, where $P$ is the identity. Thus automorphisms of $E$ fixing $P$ are automorphisms of the group.

Automorphisms of the affine curve $E -\{P\}$ extend to automorphisms of $E$ fixing $P$, since affine curves have a canonical projective closure.

A lot is known about automorphisms of elliptic curves (as groups), and we can use this to construct examples, depending on how the problem is formulated.

The main subtlety in the formulation is that an elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_p$ can have many lifts to $\mathbb Q$. Thus whether an automorphism lifts might depend on the choice of a lift of the curve.

However, it is possible to construct automorphisms that do not lift regardless of the lift of a curve. This is because, over $\mathbb Q$, every elliptic curve has automorphism group of order $2$ – the automorphisms have finite order because they fix a point on a genus $1$ curve, and they act faithfully on the tangent space at the identity, which is $\mathbb Q$, but the only finite order elements of $\mathbb Q^\times$ are $\pm 1$.

However, the curve defined by $y^2=x^3-x$ has an automorphism of order $4$ over $\mathbb F_p$ for any $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and the curve defined by $y^2 = x^3-1$ has an automorphism of order $6$ over $\mathbb F_p$ for any $p \equiv 1 \mod 6$.

You could instead ask for lifts to any field of characteristic $0$, rather than just $\mathbb Q$. In this case, we would still have examples as long as you let me choose the lifts: choosing a lift of $y^2=x^3-1$ with nonzero $j$-invariant would guarantee the order $4$ automorphism doesn't lift, and similarly for $y^2=x^3-x$ and $j\neq 1728$.

If you merely want there to exist a lift of a curve to characteristic $0$ where all the automorphisms lift, there are still counterexamples. Supersingular curves  in characteristic $2$ and $3$ have $24$ and $12$ automorphisms (over an algebraically closed field), respectively, which is more than elliptic curves can have in characteristic zero over an algebraically closed field.

However, if you wanted to find examples of a variety with some fixed automorphism that don't lift to any lift of that variety over any characteristic zero field, I believe you would have to look beyond elliptic curves.

Comment: Nice detailed answer, thanks. I would also be interested in other varieties than elliptic curves, but these are some very natural examples. Thanks.

Comment: As you pointed out, the examples you gave do not lift to $\mathbb{Q}$ but lift to some subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ (you simply need some roots of unity, right?) When you say " if you wanted to find examples of a variety with some fixed automorphism that don't lift to any lift of that variety over any characteristic zero field, I believe you would have to look beyond elliptic curves." would you have some other examples in mind?

Comment: @JérémyBlanc I don't have other examples in mind, but I'm sure they exist. (Well, technically speaking, a variety that doesn't lift would be an example, but other than those...)

Comment: @JérémyBlanc Maybe the paper John L. linked to https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2761 contains an example...

Comment: It is a conjecture of Oort that *every* automorphism of a smooth proper curve of characteristic $p$ lifts to some field of characteristic $0$ - see the file "Lifting an automorphism of a curve to characteristic zero" on his webpage. https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~oort0109/ Progress might have been made since 2003, though.

Comment: Will Sawin and Dan Petersen : thanks for the nice references. It is a nice conjecture. There might be some varieties in higher dimension where some automorphism do not lift (and of course I take a variety that lifts, as Will Sawin says).

Comment: Name of the paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380763/automorphisms-over-finite-field-that-does-not-lift-to-an-automorphism-in-charact#comment967667_380868) by @WillSawin:  [Esnault and Oguiso - Non-liftability of automorphism groups of a K3 surface in positive characteristic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2761).

Comment: @WillSawin: In my mail (Example 2) I explain why you cannot lift an automorphism of a scheme defined in characteristic $p>0$ to an automorphism of a scheme defined over the rational numbers. Hence your statement is not true.